# Regarding distribution certificate expiry how this will effect my already live app on the App Store

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, app-store

I have gone through many of the questions but still cant figure out.I have few questions in mind-

1-What will happen to my app which is live on the app store??
I think it wont be affected.

2-Do i need to revoke it now ?? or should i wait for the expiry and get the renew button as i have read and renew it then?What is the difference between both the case?

3-If i renew and get the new certificate then what measures do i have consider when submitting a new version to the app which is already live on the app store?

Do i have to create a new provisioning profile with the app bundle which i have used for the app which is live on the app store?and submit a update for the app?

Anyone please share your experience regarding this.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be fine. Nothing will happen to your live app. 
The certificate is only used when submitting to Apple. If you want to submit a new version of your app, you will need to renew your certificate before doing so.

There is no difference between revoke or waiting for it to expire. The revoke is there in case your certificate is compromised in some way.

The only measures you need to be aware of, is to delete the old (outdated) certificate from your machine, before downloading the new one, as duplicates can cause issues sometimes.

Comment: thanks amit for your response but can you please enlighten me on "The revoke is there in case your certificate is compromised in some way." compromised??as in???

Comment: For instance, if your computer/certificate was stolen, you wouldn't want people uploading apps using your certificate. Revoking it would make it invalid.